# Too many WAL archive file created in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I have configured file base - log shipping replication in postgreSql 9.4. I have default checkpint after every 5min and WAL size of 16mb. However, postgreSql send 16mb of file after every 1sec. Is this normal? I feel it's too much of network traffic. Is there a way to improve this apart from zipping logs? How could I control log shipping frequency ?
Thanks in advance !

```
sent 16779372 bytes  received 31 bytes  11186268.67 bytes/sec
total size is 16777216  speedup is 1.00
sending incremental file list
000000010000002D00000065

sent 16779372 bytes  received 31 bytes  11186268.67 bytes/sec
total size is 16777216  speedup is 1.00
sending incremental file list
000000010000002D00000066
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that archive_timeout was set to 10 sec. Hence it was creating too many WAL file copies. I just updated it to archive_timeout = 60 to make sure that it would archive WAL segment only after 1 min.

Comment: On a recent PostgreSQL version you'll also find that the WAL segments are mostly zeroes if they get rotated early. So they compress *extremely* well.